# Div not aligning properly using css grid

Tags: css, grid-system

I'm using the 960 Grid System on this page where I list my instapaper bookmarks: http://labs.tonyhue.com/bookmarks/

However, the social media section is set off from the rest. It should be aligned to the right following the programming section. Any ideas?

Comment: Should programming section align to right as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a (fixed) height to your `.grid_6`-Container.

```
.grid_6 {height:250px; /*or something else*/}
```

Your Problem occurs on floated elements with different height.

Nice reading about floatings: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

**Edit:**
Otherwise you could add a wrapper element to clear your floats:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="grid_6"></div>
     <div class="grid_6"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="grid_6"></div>
     <div class="grid_6"></div>
</div>
```

You can clear your floats with `.wrapper {overflow:hidden;}` **OR** you can use the clearfix method: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/

Comment: That makes sense. I added <div class="clear"></div> after each row. Sorta the same thing, less semantic.

Comment: Sure… name it whatever you like :)